# Why do my threads always seem to be idle?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MsgSubscriber extends JedisPubSub {

    private final PersistenceService service;
    private final ExecutorService pool;

    public MsgSubscriber(DataSource dataSource) {
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        service = new PersistenceServiceImpl(dataSource);
    }

    public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
        pool.execute(new Handler(message, service));
    }
}
```

It is subscribed to a Redis channel, which is receiving hundreds of messages a second.

I am processing each of these messages as they come along and saving them to a data store, the handler looks like this:

```
public class Handler implements Runnable {
  private String msg;
  private PersistenceService service;

  public MessageHandler(String msg, PersistenceService service) {
    this.msg = msg;
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      service.save(msg);
  }
}
```

Things seem to be working ok, messages are being written to the database, but I have been running Java VisualVM and am seeing graphs like the following:

[image: Java Visual VM]

I'm concerned because the threads seem to be sitting in this "Parked" state and not running - although with some logging statements I am seeing that the code is being run. I guess my question is firstly, is there a problem with my code, and secondly, why is Visual VM showing me the threads don't seem to be doing anything?

Comment: Just guessing here, but maybe because the handling/saving takes so little effort and the threads run for such a short time, that it is improbable to catch them "in the act"... maybe integrate some sleep functions or dummy loops for your testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> hundreds of messages a second

Redis can easily handle 10K messages per second in 1 thread.  With 4 threads it should be well under 1% busy, however this might be too low for VisualVM to detect with sampling and instead it says it is Parked all the time.

Comment: I don't think I understand - the 4 threads are in my own application which is subscribing to a Redis channel and processing the messages from the channel, and storing them in a database.

Comment: @jcm how busy do you expect them to be?

Comment: Ok, if I have 500 messages per second put on the queue, I would expect them to be pretty active, every time a new message gets put on the queue, I ask a thread to handle it, so if I have 500 messages/second then that's around one message every 2 milliseconds. So how can my threads be sitting idle for more than 10 seconds at a time and not processing these messages from the channel?

Comment: If each message takes less 0.1 ms to process, and if you have 4 threads with 500 messages per second, then they will be about 1% busy. When the thread is 99% idle, and the data is sampled, I would it expect it to appear idle almost all of the time.  I am not saying there isn't a problem, but this view isn't telling you whether there is or not.